# Print a set collection

Tags: java, collections, set

I'm studying Collections right now and from what i learned i saw that Set is a type of collection that don't permit duplicate elements.
Ok, i've created a class what adds three int numbers to a collection. It seems ok but the question is: how could i print this collection? I know that i could override the String method but since my elements is integer type how could i do that?
My expected output would be:
2,3,2
4,5,6

The code (Adding numbers)

```
public class adaugareNumere {
int c=0;
int f=0;
int r=0;

adaugareNumere(int c, int f, int r){
this.c=c;
this.f=f;
this.r=r;
}


}
```

Main class:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Executare {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    adaugareNumere primulRand=new adaugareNumere(2,3,2);
    adaugareNumere alDoileaRand=new adaugareNumere(2,3,2);
    adaugareNumere alTreileaRand=new adaugareNumere(4,5,6);
    Set<adaugareNumere> lista=new HashSet<adaugareNumere>();
    lista.add(primulRand);
    lista.add(alDoileaRand);
    lista.add(alTreileaRand);
    System.out.println("Elementele listei: "+Arrays.asList(lista.toString()));

}

}
```

Comment: Please respect the naming conventions: classes start with an uppercase letter. And indent your code correctly.

Comment: Also don't forget to override equals and hashcode.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to override the `toString()` method in your `adaugareNumere` class.

Example:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "adaugareNumere [c=" + c + ", f=" + f + ", r=" + r + "]";
}
```

And just give the list in the SOP statement.

```
System.out.println("Elementele listei: " + lista); // No need for `Arrays.asList()` or `toString()`.
```

Comment: Ok, i taught i could Override this method in another class but i made mistakes on my return statement. So it's a good solution. Thank you. Rate

Comment: One more question: why the duplicate elements (2,3,2) are printed two times? Aren't they supposed to be only once in Set?

Comment: @user2902894 You need to override hashcode and equals. Please read the documentation of HashSet

Comment: @user2902894 - You need to override the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods as well in that class with your own logic which would tell the `Set` as to on what basis are 2 instances of that class are supposed to be treated as equal. The default methods provided by `Object` aren't sufficient enough to determine that.

Answer (score 2):

To retrive Value from Set. Iterator could be used :

```
Iterator itr    =   lista.iterator();
while(itr.hasNext()){
        System.out.print(itr.next()+",");
    }
```

But Since you are trying to put Object in Set, the duplicate object will not be permitted but values can be duplicate